# how to get attributes from xml child with PHP

Tags: php, xml

I hope someone could give me some help here. I Have this XML file witch channelStatistics is one of several children from the main node

```
<ChannelStatistics ChannelId="DMAT" CounterDim="">
    <TotalCount>104</TotalCount>
    <DefectCounter ClassId="F1">62</DefectCounter>
    <DefectCounter ClassId="F2">34</DefectCounter>
    <DefectCounter ClassId="F3">8</DefectCounter>
</ChannelStatistics>

<ChannelStatistics ChannelI="FERRO" CounterDim="">
    <TotalCount>17</TotalCount>
    <DefectCounter ClassId="F1">2</DefectCounter>
    <DefectCounter ClassId="F2">5</DefectCounter>
    <DefectCounter ClassId="F3">10</DefectCounter>
</ChannelStatistics>
```

How do I get to the specific child (*ChannelStatistics*) and then get the data (*ClassId="F1", ClassId="F2", ClassId="F3"*) for different *ChannelId*?

I need a result like:

```
DMAT - F1=62 F2=34 F3=8     
FERRO - F1=2 F2=5 F3=10
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you using [SimpleXML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) or [XMLReader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php)?

Comment: If you tried, then show how you tried in your question: we might be able to see where you went wrong if we can see your code; but have no idea what you're doing wrong if you don't

Comment: $reader = new XMLReader();
      $reader->open("data\data.xml");


while($reader->read()) {
  if ($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT && $reader->name == 'ChannelStatistics') {
    $F1 = $reader->getAttribute('ClassId="F1"');
    $F2 = $reader->getAttribute('ClassId="F2"');
    $F3 = $reader->getAttribute('ClassId="F2"');
}

$reader->close();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using SimpleXML:

```
$obj = simplexml_load_string($str); // or use simplexml_load_file($file)

foreach($obj->ChannelStatistics as $channel){
    echo $channel->attributes()->ChannelId;

    foreach($channel->DefectCounter as $defect){
        echo $defect->attributes()->ClassId;
    }
}
```

Note: the XML must have a root node, and the ChannelStatistics should be children of the root. Otherwise modify the foreach accordingly. You can also use the syntax `$channel['ChannelId']` to get an attirbute.

Comment: I still can't get any result, but have no errors $obj = simplexml_load_file('data\data.xml');

foreach($obj->ChannelStatistics as $channel){
    echo $channel->attributes()->ChannelId;

    foreach($channel->DefectCounter as $defect){
        echo $defect->attributes()->ClassId;
    }
}

Comment: the XML file ant the following nodes /NdtReport/PieceReport/Piece/DeviceValuation/ChannelStatistics/DefectCounter

Comment: ok I got the DMATF1F2F3FerroF1F2F3 , but not the values of F1 , F2 or F3